# StartSession Timeout in uipath MDM

Tags: mobile, automation, uipath, saucelabs

I am trying to connection execute script in uipath MDM with mobile device from Sauce Lab.
Once the script is started,session is loading in MDM meanwhile session timeout in uipath studio.
I am not sure what capability or setting to extend the mobile session timeout in uipath.

Capabilties Tried:
newCommandTimeout